# javax.script.ScriptEngine fails at runtime

Tags: java, python, scriptengine

Any ideas?
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
    engine.put("hello_str", "");
    engine.eval("for i in range(10):");
    engine.eval("   hello_str += str(i)");
    Object x = engine.get("hello_str");
    System.out.println("x: " + x);
}
```

}

error is

Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: mismatched input '' expecting INDENT in  at line number 1 at column number 18
        at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:170)
        at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.compileScript(PyScriptEngine.java:76)
        at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:33)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
        at javaapplication2.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by:   File "", line 1
    for i in range(10):
                     ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input '' expecting INDENT

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to evaluate an incomplete statement in the lines:

```
engine.eval("for i in range(10):");
engine.eval("   hello_str += str(i)");
```

Here, I assume `eval()` is trying to evaluate these one-by-one, and finding nothing after the `for` is erroring out since that is an incomplete statement. Try this:

```
engine.eval("for i in range(10):\n   hello_str += str(i)");
```

The newline is not necessary in this case, but it would be if you want to include several statements in the loop body, eg:

```
engine.eval("for i in range(10):\n   hello_str += str(i)\n   print i");
```

Also note that in the example above the amount of spacing after each new line should be equal. In fact, I would suggest assembling the script string completely before evaluating it. Or better yet, read it from a separate .py file.